# Getting Windows to use a high resolution for VNC headless

Tags: windows-7, resolution, vnc

I have a Win 7 Pro x64 machine, which I run without a monitor and connect to via Real VNC.  When I connect a high res (2560x1600) monitor to it, then I can select that resolution, and VNC lets me use it as well.  However, the second I disconnect the monitor, VNC downgrades the resolution to 1920x1080, even though VNC shouldn't care.

How can I keep the VNC resolution high?

I've tried using the NVIDIA Control Panel, but it won't let me add a mode.

Comment: First consider the way VNC works on Windows – it _does not_ get its own desktop or session the way Remote Desktop would; it merely attaches to the _existing_ session like a parasite. Thus it can only use the same resolutions that the main session can.

Comment: Yes, but, when the machine is headless, why should the main session's resolution be forced lower? Whatever is lowering the resolution, and causing the main session to think it has an old VGA, should be able to be raised?

Comment: It's not headless. It still has a console session, regardless of monitors, as can be seen in `qwinsta`. (And as I mentioned, the VNC server doesn't create its own separate session, it merely parasites off the console session.)